# devise not sending reset password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

*reset_password_instruction.html*

```
<p><%= t('.greeting', :recipient => @resource.email, :default => "Hello #{@resource.email}!") %></p>

<p><%= t('.instruction', :default => "Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the link below.") %></p>

<p><%= link_to t('.action', :default => "Change my password" %></p>


<p><%= t('.instruction_2', :default => "If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.") %></p>
<p><%= t('.instruction_3', :default => "Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.") %></p>
```

Comment: Gonna need more information.  Can you paste the link you're using to send password reset instructions?  Can you paste the output of the log file to show what happens when you click the link?

Comment: I think there is template missing error because by default devise reset password instruction file name is "reset_password_instructions.html.erb" but you missed 's' in 'instruction'

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><%= link_to t('.action', :default => "Change my password") %></p>
```

should be:

```
<p><%= link_to t('.action', :default => "Change my password"), edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>
```

You are not passing url properly in your html code. So there is blank href in your code.